# On what frequency can we post without spamming?

Tags: discussion, spam

I like making riddles, image puzzles, cryptos etc about songs and musics, and I would like to share them. But since i'm a reasonnable person, I don't want to spam with a lot of questions.

here is my question, what is the recommended time lapse between two posts and what quantity should I be able to post without beeing considered a spammer?

Answer (score 10):

We don't care about the *volume* of your posts as long as they're high-quality.  As long as it's not too repetitive and it's well-made, go ahead and post! We'd love to have more puzzles here. We just don't want to see the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Deusovi's answer

There are system checks that warn you if you make too many low quality posts, or make too many posts in a short duration. Boring and repetitive puzzles anyway get down-voted. As long as you receive no such warnings, I guess it's okay to post as many puzzles as you want.

No user has the right to call you a spammer if all your posts have sufficient up-votes. But also keep in mind that the standard of questions at Puzzling SE is really high, so a puzzle that you might find interesting may be way to easy here.